# What does "Play Store signature invalid" exactly mean?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to let users sign in with Google in my Android application, after following the [standard implementation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) from the official Google Developers site, here's what I am getting on my LogCat :

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil : Google Play Store signature invalid.
```

Comment: I am guessing the api isn't setup correctly in api console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply a bad ROM with an invalid Google Play Store signature.

Answer (score 2):

That was the current time of the phone isn't correct.